# Working with apache nutch 2.2.1

Tags: java, apache, nutch, web-crawler, gora

I'm trying to start my first crawl, I've already configured the database settings and I execute the following command:  `bin/nutch inject urls`

And the bug result is the following:

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2014-07-18 08:13:34
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=inject urls, jobid=job_local1172062909_0001
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas.

What version of Gora are you using? SqlStore was only enabled on Gora 0.1, and now is a missing feature to be implemented. Sorry for the bad news :( I think it the sql module was deleted because of some license issues... I think.

Sorry for the bad news :( some day the module surely will be back.